# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name at runtime in ASP.Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H50jn.png)I am getting an SQLException pointing at the '**GetAllItems()**' method below in the ItemsService.
"Invalid column name OrderID1"

I have two entities, the Order and Item and I wanted the OrderID associated with each item to be display in the Item views (CRUD)

```
 public IEnumerable<Item> GetAllItems()
 {
     return _context.Items.ToList();
 }
```

**Items Controller**

```
    // GET: Items/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var Orders = _ordersService.GetAllOrders();
        var orderIDList = new SelectList(Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID");
        var item = new Item
        {
            OrderIDList = orderIDList
        };

        return View(item);
    }

    // POST: Items/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create([Bind("ItemID,ItemName,Price,QuantityInStock,OrderID")] Item item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _itemsService.CreateItem(item);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(item);
    }

    // GET: Items/Edit/5
    public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var item = _itemsService.GetItemByID(id.Value);

        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var Orders = _ordersService.GetAllOrders();
        var orderIDList = new SelectList(Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID");
        {
            OrderIDList = orderIDList;
        };

        return View(item);
        
    }
```

**Item Model**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace OrderEase.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Item ID")]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Item Name")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Quantity in stock")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity in stock is required")]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be non-negative.")]
        public int QuantityInStock { get; set; }

        //One-to-Many Relationship with Order
        [Display(Name ="Order ID")]
        public int OrderID { get; set; } //Foreign Key referecing Order
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

        //ViewModel-related properties
        [NotMapped]
        [ForeignKey("SelectedOrderID")]
        public int SelectedOrderID { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Order ID List")]
        public SelectList OrderIDList { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Here is my **DbContext class**:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OrderEase.Models;

namespace OrderEase.Data
{
    public class OrderDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public OrderDbContext(DbContextOptions<OrderDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        //Configure Relationships
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Using Fluent API for Configuration
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasKey(o => o.OrderID); //Configure Primary Key
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .Property(o => o.Quantity)
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .Property(o => o.TotalPrice)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasPrecision(18, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .Property(o => o.OrderDate)
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .Property(o => o.DeliveryDate)
                .IsRequired();


            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .Property(o => o.Supplier)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            //One-to-Many Relationship
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasMany(o => o.Items)
                .WithOne(i => i.Order).HasForeignKey(i => i.OrderID);

            //Item Configuration
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .HasKey(i => i.ItemID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .Property(i => i.ItemName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .Property(i => i.Price)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasPrecision(18, 2);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .Property(i => i.QuantityInStock)
                .IsRequired();

            //Relationship
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .HasOne(i => i.Order)
                .WithMany(o => o.Items)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.OrderID);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        //Defining Tables

        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What is going on, and how can I resolve this error?

Here is the rest of the code: https://github.com/Bless-Siba/OrderEase-Final/tree/master/Models

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H50jn.png)

Comment: The screenshot shared seems to be a different issue/problem as what you mentioned in the question. Would be great if you can share the Context class for the EF Fluent API for the `Item`.

Comment: Error in screen shot indicates a connection issue.  Check the connection string.  How long before error occurs.  Default timeout for a query is 30 seconds.  Error may be your connection never completed.  Use SQL Server Management Studio and make sure you can connect to database.  The c# error can be seen in the database log files which can be see using SSMS in the explorer under Management.

Comment: @YongShun I am so sorry I attached the wrong screenshot. Kindly see the updated post.

Comment: @jdweng I updated the post. Please see the screenshot now.

Comment: Looks like you may of changed a property in the Entity Mode and did not perform a migration.  There is a mapping between the entity classes and the database tables/fields.  The error indicates the mapping is not correct.  Try performing a migration to update the mapping.

Comment: Oh, now that you mentioned it, I created a mapping class for the CSV function. So the mapping class has the same properties as the Order model property. Could it be that? However, if you view the screenshot I provided, the error occurs in the Itwm service, pointing at GetAllItems()

Comment: When adding a Migration it gives  an erro indicating that there is an existing property “OrderID”

Comment: Please reduce this into a [mre]. We don't need the entire service or controller. After all, it's *only* one simple `ToList()` that throws. And of course the classes and mapping code *in the question* (not in a transient github link) + no images, but text.

Comment: Migration has two modes 1) Create 2) Update.  Are you running Update?

Comment: @jdweng I did not run Update because there was an alert indicating that there is already an OrderID

Comment: @GertArnold I am so sorry. I'll update the post

Comment: Create is not going to work if it already exists.  Create will give error since it already exists.  You need to run Update and just ignore the warning since you know that it already exists and want to revise.

Comment: @jdweng I am attempting this and I am getting an error 'The entity type 'SelectListGroup' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating.' Can you checkout my comment to Steve Py's answer below. I explained why I added these ViewModel entities. Kindly advise if I should omit or keep them. I couldn't find a way to utilize the navigation property to display OrderIDs associated with Items in the CRUD views for the Item entity. Please advise on how I can go about this.

Comment: Migration updates the database tables and fields from the c# classes. Looks like database has SelectListGroup marked as a key, but the c# classes do not.  You must of added SelectListGroup to a c# class and didn't indicate it was a key.  It was already marked as a key in the database.  You have to add the attribute to the c# class.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

When a foreign key is used by multiple time (by many relations), the column's name is followed by a number, like `OrderID1`.

---

In your case, the foreign key property `Item.OrderID` is used in these two relationships :

```cs
public class Item
{
    ...
    public int OrderID { get; set; }Order
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    ...
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

The navigation property `Order.Items` use the foreign key `Item.OrderID` as defined in `OnModelCreating`.

The navigation property `Order.Item` isn't defined in `OnModelCreating`, but by convention it's linked to `Item.Order` that use the foreign key `Item.OrderID`.

The property `Item.OrderID` is used two times as foreign key and mapped to column `OrderID` and `OrderID1`...

---

The solution is to specify the foreign key to all navigation properties like :

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasMany(o => o.Items)
        .WithOne(i => i.Order)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.OrderID);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasOne(o => o.Item)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Order>("ItemId");
}
```

Comment: No, these mappings are identical. Sure, one is redundant, but EF doesn't add them up.

Comment: @GertArnold, indeed. I do some test and confirm. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a bit more to your Item table, or possibly another entity you have not included. For instance:

```
    [NotMapped]
    [ForeignKey("SelectedOrderID")]
    public int SelectedOrderID { get; set; }
```

This is not valid. The `[ForeignKey]` attribute can be put on either the FK property or the navigation property, but if on the FK property it should point to the navigation property, not itself. I.e. `[ForeignKey("SelectedOrder")]`. It would never be combined with a `[NotMapped]` attribute. That tells EF this is not related to a column in the database.

AS for the dual mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .HasMany(o => o.Items)
    .WithOne(i => i.Order).HasForeignKey(i => i.OrderID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
    .HasOne(i => i.Order)
    .WithMany(o => o.Items)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.OrderID);
```

You should remove one or the other. Pick an entity to serve as the root for a relationship and configure it from that side. While having both mappings shouldn't cause problems, it opens the door to leaving something misconfigured resulting in errors or "weird" behaviour.

As for the error itself, this is commonly caused by a bad assumption about EF's convention around resolving FKs. EF can locate FKs such as:

```
public int OrderId { get; set; }
public Order Order { get; set; }
```

... where you don't even need to add a `[ForeignKey]` attribute or set up the mapping with the modelBuilder.  However, many expect that it should also figure out something like:

```
public int SelectedOrderId { get; set; }
public Order SelectedOrder { get; set; }
```

... except it won't. It will actually look for something like OrderId1 given the entity already has an "Order" navigation property and FK; similar to the error you are seeing. The EF convention is based on the Type of the navigation property, not the property name. If SelectedOrder is a type Order, EF is using that as the basis for the FK name. This means that a `[ForeignKey]` attribute or modelBuilder mapping is required.  In your case you have a "SelectedOrderID" property which is suspicious, but I don't see a "SelectedOrder" navigation property which may, or may not exist. If you have other entities in your system set up, look for any that have a navigation property of Type "Order" that have a different name, and be sure that these are explicitly mapped.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. This is very insightful and I really appreciate your patience and how you addressed it. I have omitted the unnecessary [NotMapped] attributes in my 'Item' entity.  What led to this mismatch/confusion is the need to display the OrderID associated with each Item in the CRUD for Item. I utilized scaffolding, which came with pre-designed views which I was trying to adjust to my application requirements. I actually wanted to utilize the navigation property for this but I don't know how. In a nutshell, the confusion stemmed from the Views (requirements).

Comment: So what must I do with the SelectedOrderID and SelectedOrder. These are ViewModel-related properties I created because I had a challenge trying to display the OrderID in the Item CRUD views as mentioned in the above comment. Is there maybe an alternative to this? You can also check out the GitHub link provided in the post to see the rest ,of the code and for better insight to this. Your help is really appreciated sir

Comment: If there is a SelectedOrder, it would need to be marked as [NotMapped] as well. However, I would recommend keeping domain model (Entities) and ViewModels as separate concerns and separate classes. Entities are meant to reflect data state and it is not a good idea to do things like send them to views and back. (Even though a lot of examples from MS do just that) When entities only reflect data state concerns there are fewer things to go wrong & exceptions to the rules needed.